# Sorting objects aplhabetically in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static Winner [] listOfWinners;

    public static void loadFromFile()
    {
        try{
            //Create instance of Scanner and provide instance of File pointing to the txt file
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("WorldSeriesWinners.txt"));

            //Get the number of teams
            int years = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();//move to the next line

            //Create the array
            listOfWinners = new Winner[years];

            //for every year in the text file
            for(int index = 0; index<years; index++)
            {
                //Get the year
                int year = input.nextInt();
                input.skip("    ");
                //Get the team
                String team = input.nextLine();

                //Create an instance of Winner and add it to the next spot in the array
                listOfWinners[index] = new Winner(team,year);
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong when loading the file!");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void sortByTeamName()
    {

    }
```

I've been searching online for a few hours but cannot figure out a way to properly sort the array alphabetically

Comment: Make it into list and just call `Collections.sort()`?  or just simply do  `Arrays.sort()`

Comment: I cannot use Array.sort because the array contains both numbers and letters

Comment: You could use a different data structure that would sort the items as you insert them

Comment: Yes, you can use that method. You give it a Comparator, as the below answer shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following snippet for sorting by Team name, by taking advantage of the comparator feature of the [Arrays.sort(arr[],comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator))

```
Arrays.sort(listOfWinners, new Comparator<Winner>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Winner o1, Winner o2) {

                return o1.team.compareTo(o2.team);
            }
        });
```